# Error, command already defined - IOP article with mhchem

Tags: errors, lyx

I am using LyX to prepare an article. The document class is 'IOP article' and I am using the mhchem package to typeset chemical formulae in the paper. I include `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` in the LaTeX preamble.

I am thrown 11 errors when I try to preview the document:

- LaTeX Error: Command \leftroot already defined.
- LaTeX Error: Command
  \uproot already defined.
- etc..

Suggestion/solutions much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The real problem is not `mhchem` but `amsmath` which is loaded implicitly by `mhchem` and seems to be incompatible with the `iopart` class. Do you need many chemical formulae and even reactions?

Comment: You might be able to overcome the problem by adding the following magic just before loading `mhchem`: `\makeatletter\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}\makeatother`

Comment: @egreg's suggestion should work if you also load `amstext` before loading `mhchem` as the latter relies on the macro `\text` (which is why it loads `amsmath` in the first place, I guess)

Comment: I've reverse-duped here as the newer question is clearer (and has a better answer) than this one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be solved with the following loading order/definitions:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```