# Command already defined - IOP publication with mhchem

Tags: incompatibility, mhchem

I am using `iopart` class for IOP publication, and I want use the `mhchem` package for writing chemical equations. I ran into the same problem as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94119/error-command-already-defined-iop-article-with-mhchem) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199290/error-undefined-control-sequence-argument-rightarrowfill), old topics without answer. I compile with pdflatex in Texmaker the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
%\usepackage{iopams} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\title[mytitle]{mytitle}
\author{myauthor}

\begin{abstract}
A minimal non-working iopart + mhchem example
\end{abstract}

\ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}

\end{document}
```

This throws back the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \equation* already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2664 }
```

I added the advice in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94119/error-command-already-defined-iop-article-with-mhchem):

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amstext}
```

before `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}`. I have no clue what it means.
But it raises plenty of errors :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \rightarrowfill@ 
                            \displaystyle 
l.18 \ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18 \ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@begin@tempboxa ...begingroup #2\color@endgroup }
                                                  \def \width {\wd \@tempbox...
l.18 \ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18 \ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.18 \ce{P ->[\sigma_{P}] T}
```

EDIT: Following comments below I tried :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
%\usepackage{iopams} 

\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\title[mytitle]{mytitle}
\author{myauthor}

\begin{abstract}
A minimal working iopart + chemformula example
\end{abstract}

\ch{P ->[$\sigma$] T} \par

\end{document}
```

And it does the job !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. `\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` lets every following package think that `amsmath` had been loaded which in this case prevents `mhchem` from loading it. Unfortunately for you `mhchem` *needs* `amsmath`…

Comment: The workaround should work with [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula), though.

Comment: Thanks all 
@clemens : I tried the same with chemformula `(\usepackage{chemmacros}) `. with the \@namedef workaround. It throws error on mathtools.sty : `! LaTeX Error: Environment gathered undefined.` and `! LaTeX Error: \aligned@a undefined.`. 

chemformula use packages l3kernel[The13a], xparse, l3keys2e and xfrac said the user's guide. Maybe I should force it to load only those, instead of bundle ? But how ?

Comment: it won't work with `chemmacros` which is why I suggested `chemformula`

Comment: `chemformula` has another syntax than `mhchem`! You have to explicitly switch to mathmode. Use `\ch{P ->[$\sigma_{P}$] T}` or `\ch{P ->[$\sigma$ _{P} ] T}` depending on the meaning of the `P`. (BTW: instead of editing this question it would have been better to ask a new question since this is unrelated to the original issue)

Comment: Ok thanks. Nice workaround. Maybe it is related to the absence of loading of `amsmath`, but the subscript  `_{P}` in `\ch{P ->[$\sigma_{P}$] T}` doesn't draw well. Please correct me if I am out of topic.

Comment: not a workaround but the recommended way as explained in the `chemformula` manual. `$\sigma_{P}$` looks the same if with `amsmath` or `without`. What do you mean with »doesn't draw well«?

Comment: By workaround I mean using `chemformula` instead of `mhchem`. `P` in `_P` doesn't show up as subscript, but in full size and the underscore is visible.

Comment: Ah. Try `\ch{P ->[ "$\sigma_{P}$" ] T}` (note the spaces!)

Comment: Ok, the spaces did it. Thanks ! Maybe you can move your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Form the file `ioplatexguidelines.pdf`:

[image]

Since `mhchem` loads and, more importantly, requires `amsmath`, you have two options: stick to `iopart.cls` and don't use `mhchem` but another package offering a similar functionality, or change your document class and use `mhchem`; as the guideline mentions this is not a problem since they will accept your document written using any other document class.

Comment: And the reason why `iopart` doesn't want `amsmath` just to use their badly defined environments is very obscure.

Answer (score 3):

The two approaches below woks for me. They are really a huge help.

(1)

```
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax

\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
```

Put these just before \usepackage{amsmath}

(2)

Alternatively, edit iopart.cls and remove (or comment) these two
lines (lines 788 and 789 in my copy):

```
\@namedef{equation*}{\[}

\@namedef{endequation*}{\]}
```

originally from

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/mgzSLY8zCa8

Answer (score 2):

I recently across the same problem between iopart and amsmath. The warning I saw was "Command \equation* already defined." I fixed it by commenting out these two lines:

```
\@namedef{equation*}{\[}
\@namedef{endequation*}{\]}
```

in iopart.cls (lines 788-789 for me). It seems that they want

```
\begin{equation*}
F=ma
\end{equation*}
```

to be just

```
\[F=ma\]
```

for some reason which is kind of stupid. I don't think commenting these lines out will break anything else, but I'm not sure.