# Formatting long equation with iopart

Tags: equations, formatting

I need to write the following long equation in my paper with the template given by IOP, iopart:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dN}{d(\hbar\omega)} &= \frac{\alpha}{12\pi}\, \frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{1+\beta(K)} \frac{|\vec{\Delta\beta}|^2}{\hbar\omega}=\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{12\pi}\frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{\hbar\omega(1+\beta(K))}\left( \frac{2mc^2 K+ K^2}{(mc^2+K)^2} + \frac{2mc^2 (K-\hbar\omega)+ (K-\hbar\omega)^2}{(mc^2+K-\hbar\omega)^2} + 2\frac{m^2c^4-K(K-\hbar\omega)}{m^2c^4} \right) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Normally I would use `split` as above, but with this template it is not possible. Their guidelines say that one should use `\fl` in order to align multiline equations, so I have tried with:

```
\begin{equation}
\fl \frac{dN}{d(\hbar\omega)} = \frac{\alpha}{12\pi}\, \frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{1+\beta(K)} \frac{|\vec{\Delta\beta}|^2}{\hbar\omega}=\\
\fl =\frac{\alpha}{12\pi}\frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{\hbar\omega(1+\beta(K))}\left( \frac{2mc^2 K+ K^2}{(mc^2+K)^2} + \frac{2mc^2 (K-\hbar\omega)+ (K-\hbar\omega)^2}{(mc^2+K-\hbar\omega)^2} + 2\frac{m^2c^4-K(K-\hbar\omega)}{m^2c^4} \right) 
\end{equation}
```

but it gives this result:

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The `\fl` command what is it, `\lefteqn`?

Comment: @Sebastiano It seems their own  implementation of \lefteqn. IOP has defined its own package that is incompatible with the one by ams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've noted, the `iopart` document class doesn't let you use the `amsmath` package and its multi-line display-math environments. However, it provides a re-implementation of LaTeX's venerable `eqnarray` environment, which seems suitable for the job at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{esvect} % for \vv macro (alternative for \vec)
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\mathrm{d}N}{\mathrm{d}(\hbar\omega)}
&= \frac{\alpha}{12\pi} \, \frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{1+\beta(K)} 
   \frac{|\vv{\Delta\beta}|^2}{\hbar\omega} \nonumber\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{12\pi} \, \frac{4+\beta(K)+\beta(K)^2}{\hbar\omega(1+\beta(K))}
   \biggl( \frac{2mc^2 K+ K^2}{(mc^2+K)^2}\\
&\quad+ \frac{2mc^2 (K-\hbar\omega)+ (K-\hbar\omega)^2}{(mc^2+K-\hbar\omega)^2} 
   + 2\,\frac{m^2c^4-K(K-\hbar\omega)}{m^2c^4} \biggr) \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What could I do if I have an equation on two lines and I need to number it? I *do not* want the equation number only on the last line.

Comment: @Eddymage - Do you employ the `iopart` document class? If not, do please say which document class you use.

Comment: Yes, I am using the `iopart` class (unfortunately). Actually, I am using this [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596769/211707) and everything works fine with `iopart`, and I hope that the journal will accept this in the preamble.